# Unable to run dart command for specific device dart -d

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter and dart is installed successfully. I am able to run a dart file successfully using command line. e.g

```
//main.dart
void main() {
  print('Hello, World!');
}
```

when i run `dart main.dart` i can see the output in command line but i am not able to run dart -d command i.e to run a dart test or dart file with specific device or device id.

Comment: Are you sure that `dart -d` should not be `flutter -d`?. Dart does not know anything about devices since that is part of Flutter. :)

Comment: to run test using a package flutter_gherkin it requires us to run with dart command line

Comment: Can you explain why that is needed? If your program is making use of Flutter, you should run it with the `flutter` command and not `dart`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to separate:
The code you showed as example is native Dart without Flutter. So yes your output get only printed in the CommandLine.

If you want a Flutter Project and use the `-d` argument you first need to set up a Flutter Project using `flutter create project_name` then you can experiment around and show what you want to the world.

Useful resources which help you to get started:
[Write your first Flutter app [flutter.dev Tutorial]](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab)
[More or less a Flutter Roadmap](https://flutter.dev/learn)